# Is it possible to limit the maximum number of buffers saved with desktop?

Tags: emacs

I use `(desktop-save-mode 1)` in my `.emacs`. After some time of working with it my `.emacs.desktop` contains many `(desktop-create-buffer...)` entries which slow down startup terribly. Is it possible to limit the number of saved buffers to some arbitrary number?

Comment: See the variables `desktop-restore-eager`; `desktop-lazy-verbose`; `desktop-lazy-idle-delay`.  No need to limit what gets saved, just limit what gets restored and how it gets restored.  However, there are also exclusion options for saving.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks @lawlist

Answer (score 1):

For total control, you could advise the function `desktop-save-buffer-p` such that it returns `nil` for all the buffers you don't want to be saved.

By default that uses three user options:

- `desktop-buffers-not-to-save` (regexp)
- `desktop-files-not-to-save` (regexp)
- `desktop-modes-not-to-save` (list)

Those don't directly help you cap the number of buffers saved to a specific limit, but they may prove useful regardless.

You might adapt code from `midnight.el` (e.g. a variant of `clean-buffer-list` which just returns a buffer list rather than killing buffers) to make use of existing code for identifying old/unnecessary buffers.

Comment: it does seem like it would be useful to have an additional hook somewhere in here. Ill just add that personally, I find it useful to maintain multiple desktop sessions for different projects to avoid the long startup issue.

Comment: Oh wait, there is the `desktop-save-hook` where you could add a function to truncate the list.

Comment: `desktop-save-hook` could be used to generate the list of interest before saving begins, but there's no standard way to tell `desktop-save-buffer-p` to include/exclude files or buffers based on such a list, other than generating those regexps with `regexp-opt` which would be kinda gross IMO -- better to use advice than do that (but an enhancement to provide a standard method would be nice).

Comment: agreed, it looks like you could run a function there to shorten the `buffer-list` tho, but maybe that would necessarily involve killing those buffer (which might be fine). I use the desktop-files-not-to-save regex to leave out directories, but you're right its pretty gross

Comment: Right, if *killing* the buffers is acceptable then you could do that in the existing hook.  But if that was the goal then you'd probably use `midnight-mode` instead.

Comment: Killing buffers is acceptable, but it turns out CleanBufferList which is run by midnight-mode doesn't work with DeskTop :-( https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CleanBufferList

Comment: Right, I see. That looks like [bug #15262](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15262), if anyone fancies attending to it.